# How to create choose sidebar template layout in WordPress under post section?

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I would like to know (or create something similar like this ) how to create choose sidebar template (sidebar layout) under post section in WordPress. I just need a link to refer. Can anyone suggest me relate link so that I can refer it? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called WordPress meta box. You can always find a lot of the information on the internet.